# Bypassing drupal cache in template file

Tags: 7, theming, caching

is there a way i can bypass the drupal cache for a specific element on my website?
in my case i've got 3 header graphics which should be displayed at a random order on every page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes), JavaScript or setting the image to a php file is how to get around the caching issue.
http://drupal.org/project/esi_api
http://drupal.org/project/esi
http://drupal.org/project/ajaxify_regions
http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks
http://drupal.org/project/views_javascript_random
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/randomizer

Answer (score 1):

The entire page is being cached, so you'll want to disable caching on those pages that have dynamic elements. I think you'd want to:

a) turn OFF page caching for the needed paths (http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude)
b) turn ON caching for any Views, blocks, or whatever else you can cache on those pages to save bandwidth

Then you'll have more granular caching control.